# Setting frame pos in OpenCV never works

Tags: python, opencv

I am attempting to set the frame pos to half way through a video. But it never works. When I play the video it always starts from the beginning.

Any idea whats going wrong?

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture()

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) * 0.5)) 
#cap.set(1, int(cap.get(7) * 0.5)) # try just using the enumeration values (still doesn't work)

cap.open('./images/billboard1.mp4')

while 1:
    _, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame) # always shows the first frame not half way through

    ...
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to set the position after you open the file, rather than before? If there's no file open, there's nowhere to seek to (nor can you get a meaningfull result when querying frame count).

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the frame position on an empty VideoCapture object.

try

`ret = cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) * 0.5))
print(ret)`

before you open the capture, and after you open the capture to see what happens (since for some reason this function doesn't throw an error). `cap.set` will return 0 or -1 (can't remember) if the set was unsuccessful.